# how to get data from firebase document?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from `Firebase` but I cannot figure out how. This is how it looks at the moment.

This is how I set the data:

```
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('videos')
          .doc(id)
          .collection("uservotes")
          .doc(uid)
          .set({'videoid': id, 'rating': _rating, 'uid': uid});
```

What I need now is to get the data in the same way, but how? I need the `'rating'` field value .
Hope anyone can help

Comment: Try this link: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#read-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the `id` and `uid`, then you can just do:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("videos").doc(id).collection("uservotes").doc(uid).get().then((value){
      print(value.data()); //contains all the data
      print(value.data()["rating"]);
    });
```

Using `get()` you can retrieve the all the fields inside the document.